# Including folder outside src for TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript

I need to add a generated folder, which is neither part of global ambient nor in the `src`, to supply modules for the source files as valid namespaces, such as below:

```
root
|- src
   |-- component
       |-- test.model.ts ( import { IBuilding } from 'api/interfaces.ts' );
|- generated
   |-- api
       | interfaces.ts ( export interface IBuilding {} )
```

I have read about **Modules** and **Module Resolution** in official documentation but none of the options below see to apply:

- tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions.paths (path mapping)
- tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions.rootDirs (virtual directory)
- tsconfig.json -> include (file name patterns)

In my case it would be very much similar to what `CLASSPATH` and `PYTHON_PATH` do for Java and Python respectively.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you could do this in your `tsconfig.json` with a `filesGlob`:

```
"filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts", //Local source, this is the default
    "../generated/**/*.ts" //generated source
], //Add as many directories to the above list as needed
```

Comment: whats the difference between filesGlob and includes?